# Deleting rows if found in multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, row

I am having trouble with deleting a row that can be found in 2 of my arrays.

I have 2 arrays:

```
array1 = 1 2
         3 4
         5 6
         7 8
         9 10

array2 = 1 5
         7 8
         3 2
```

If the row appears in both arrays I want to delete it from `array1` (example `[7,8]`). I tried this line of code below:

```
array1( find(array1(:,1) == array2(:,1)) ,:) = [];
```

but I am getting the following error message:

> Error using  == Matrix dimensions must agree.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `ismember`, for example, if your arrays are `a` and `b`:

```
a(ismember(a,b,'rows'),:)=[];
```

should do the job.

Comment: Didn't know about the `'rows'` argument for `ismember`. Very clean.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I had a loop set up but it was messy.

Answer (score 1):

[`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) is more direct and allows you to preserve the original array if needed:

```
setdiff(array1,array2,'rows','stable')
```

---

Just for reference, you can also use [`interect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html):

```
[~,ia] = intersect(array1,array2,'rows');
array1(ia,:) = [];
```

However, I would use `setdiff`.